# Report that joins Campaigns, Contacts, and custom objects

Tags: custom-object, joined-reports

I have a custom object (called Publications), which is related to Contacts through a Publication Contact Relation object, with Publications and Contacts as master-detail fields.  I would like to generate a report that shows all Publications for Contacts who are members of a Campaign.

I've created a "Campaign with Contacts" report in joined format, then added report type "Contacts with Publication Contact Relations and Publications", but the only common field is Owner.

Is there a way to create a report that joins all the way through from Campaign to Contacts to a Custom object (Publications, in my case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create a custom report type

In Setup, under App Setup, expand the Create section and select Report Types.  Create a new report type with Campaigns as the primary object, then Contacts as the A to B relationship, and Publications as the B to C relationship.